# how to get geolocation city name in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, geolocation, ios6-maps

I have tried this codes for getting the geolocation based values but not able to get the city name. How do I get the city name?

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
    double lati = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
   _geo_coder_latitude_lbl.text= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lati] retain];
   _geocoder_latitude_str=_geo_coder_latitude_lbl.text;
   NSLog(@"print lat;%@",_geocoder_latitude_str);
   double longi = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
   _geocoder_longitude_lbl.text= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longi] retain];
   _geocoder_longitude_str=_geocoder_longitude_lbl.text;
   NSLog(@"print lat;%@",_geocoder_longitude_str);
  [self._geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {

     //Get address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     NSLog(@"Placemark array: %@",placemark.addressDictionary );

     //String to address

     _located_address = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

     //Print the location in the console

     NSLog(@"Currently address is: %@",_located_address);

    // _ex_map_address_lbl.text=_located_address;

 }];

  [self _storeList_json_parser];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the CLPlacemark [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html), `[CLPlacemark locatity]` will return the city name associated with the placemark.

Check this sample code:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
double lati = 45.46433;
double longi = 9.18839;

CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi) 
                                                     altitude:0 
                                           horizontalAccuracy:0
                                             verticalAccuracy:0 
                                                   timestamp:[NSDate date]];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
         if (error || !placemark)
             return;

         NSString *city = placemark.locality;
         if (!city)
             city = placemark.subAdministrativeArea;

         NSLog(@"City for location: %@", city);
}];
```

Comment: yes, i have try this placemark.locality some time city name came but some time placemark.locality response  shows null value .how can i get standard response in city name.

Comment: What if you fallback with subAdministrativeArea? See the updated code.

Comment: Ya fine,but some placemark fields response shows null value .e.g it's shows: Placemark locality: Coimbatore
 Placemark subLocality: (null)
 Placemark subAdministrativeArea: (null)
 Placemark thoroughfare: Siddhapudur Road
 Placemark subThoroughfare: (null)
 Placemark name: Siddhapudur Road
 Placemark country: India
 Placemark administrativeAreay: Tamil Nadu
 City for location: Coimbatore
 Wat the reason it's shows null values some time?

Comment: MKReverseGeocoder can be unreliable for certain locations. See http://bit.ly/Senltl